# JMS Not consuming message after setting up temporary queue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, jms

I have set up a simple request/reply type scenario (JavaEE 7/Netbeans 7 with Glassfish) with code as follows:

This is a stateless session bean performing the JMS producer role
`destination` and `factory` are injected into the EJB.

```
public void doStuff(int id) {

    try {
    Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();

    MyObject obj = new MyObject(id);
    connection.start();

    TemporaryQueue replyQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(replyQueue);

    message.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);
    message.setObject(obj);

    producer.send(message, DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, 1800000);
    Message reply = consumer.receive();

    producer.close();
    session.close();
    connection.close();
    } catch (JMSException ex) {

    }
    }
```

My problem is that when `consumer.receive()` is called, execution blocks as expected - however the consumer of this message never runs. The consumer of the original message (it's an MDB) is located in another netbeans project deployed on the same Glassfish server.

I have tried debugging both projects (both the producer and consumer) and it seems like while my producer project is blocking, my consumer project doesn't do anything at all.

If I change `consumer.recieve()` to something like `consumer.receive(20000)` then as expected nothing happens for 20 seconds - but as soon as the timeout expires all of a sudden I get a debugger breakpoint hit on my consumer project and it processes as normal. But of course no reply is sent back to my producer project because it's no longer listening!

My other project (the consumer project) looks something like this:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/myQueue")
})
---------------------
    @Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        ObjectMessage objMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
        MyObject obj = (MyObject) objMessage.getObject();
        Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(message.getJMSReplyTo());
        connection.start();

        try {
            myMethod(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Message response = session.createTextMessage(e.getMessage());
            producer.send(message.getJMSReplyTo(), response);
        }


    } catch (JMSException ex) {

    }
}
```

How can I get the receive() method to work correctly? I need it to pause for a reply, but while pausing I need my other project to continue working - and I'd assume they're on different threads anyway if they're two separately deployed projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered that I was getting this issue because my `doStuff()` method was running a Container Managed Transaction.

In addition to this, you can only perform one action per transaction (eg: Only one of the request/receive)

So when I was calling `producer.send()`, the message wasn't actually sent because the transaction had not finished yet (the method was not finished). It then went on to the `receive` call and blocked there since no message was sent.

I worked around this by making my doStuff() method a Bean Managed Transaction, I injected a `UserTransaction` object with the `@Resource` annotation on the bean.

I went to bound the send action by `UserTransaction.begin` and `UserTransaction.commit` and I repeated this to bind my second receive action - it worked as expected.

This provided me with a clear explanation on CMTs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncij/index.html